# ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED reports every one level change in battery

Tags: android, batterylevel

I am using a BroadcastReceiver to monitor battery level changes.

```
 // register the battery action receiver
    mContext.registerReceiver(this, new IntentFilter(
            Intent.ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED));
```

OnReceive method is called every one level change in Battery. Is it possible to change the granularity at which the ACTION_BATTERY_CHANGED is received?

Comment: You could listen for `ACTION_BATTERY_LOW` and `ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY`. or check level.. if level == your_level { do something }

Comment: You can use time difference when the broadcast firing to achieve the task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible to set the interval between battery percentage as far as I know. However, you could filter it yourself by saving the last level at which you updated it then check if it is lower or equal to the amount you are checking for. Alternatively, you could check if it is a multiple of something (ie. 5) before continuing. Also, as Marco said, you can use other types of Intents (ie. ACTION_BATTERY_LOW or ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY) depending on what your app does.

Comment: My application operates in the background, I am saving the frequency of waking up from background to receive battery changes. Also, threshold for battery is a configurable parameter in my application, ACTION_BATTERY_LOW or ACTION_BATTERY_OKAY reports only predefined battery levels.